# TinyMCE paste plugin on IE 11 on paste, pasting %%MCEPASTEBIN%% instead of the actual text and getting stack overflown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, editor, internet-explorer-11

[image]

I am using **tinyMCE v5.5.1** with **paste plugin v5.6.2**. On pasting anything in the tinyMCE editor in IE11, it gets stack overflown and pastes **%%MCEPASTEBIN%%** until the browser stops responding. It works fine on Chrome, firefox etc.

There was already a github issue created for problem similar to this https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4974 and the PR seems to have been merged but I'm still getting the same issue.

Without the paste plugin everything works fine, but I need the paste_postprocess functionality being provided by paste plugin.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported to mix the core editor from one version (5.5.1) and a plugin from a different version (5.6.2).  They are not tested in that fashion and there is no guarantee that they will ever work together in this fashion.

If you wish to use the `paste` plugin from 5.6.2 you need to update the entire editor to 5.6.2 not just one plugin.

If you test this on TinyMCE Fiddle using 5.6.2 in its entirety do you still get this issue?

I would also note TinyMCE is now at 5.7 so if you are doing an update it would make sense to move to the latest TinyMCE release.